# How capture photo then iOS-app is minimized?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, avcapturesession

How take picture from camera when iOS-app is minimized?
(i.e. after `applicationDidEnterBackground:` / `applicationWillResignActive:` )

**AppDelegate.m:** ([thank you link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17591384/1309648))

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    //To make the code block asynchronous
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        //### background task starts
        NSLog(@"Running in the background\n");
        while(TRUE)
        {
            printf("Called"); //////Work fine

            [self.window.rootViewController captureNow]; /////Capture picture!

            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 10.0]; //wait for 10 sec
        }
    });

    return YES;
}
```

**OurViewController.m:** ([thank you link](http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/ios4-take-photos-with-live-video-preview-using-avfoundation/))

```
-(IBAction)captureNow {

    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in _stillImageOutput.connections)
    {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts])
        {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] )
            {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoConnection)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", _stillImageOutput);
    [_stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
     {
         CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment( imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);

         if (error)
         {
             NSLog(@"ERROR = %@", error); ///// Error!
         }

         NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer]; ////SIGABRT, cause imageSampleBuffer is nil
         UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

         UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);

         [image release];
     }];
}
```

This code works fine, when application is active. But take error (SIGABRT), when app is minimized.

Maybe are there other libraries can afford to do it?

Comment: You're not allowed access to the camera while in the background. There's probably a way around for jailbreak apps using private APIs, but you'll never get app store approval.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090184/how-does-the-ios-app-display-recorder-record-the-screen-without-using-private-ap

Answer (score 5):

For privacy reasons, you're not allowed to access the camera when your app is in the background.

Why?

Well, I'm glad you asked that. Story time!

---

Bob is a person who works at the NSA, developing super-secret monkey controlling sharks. Why? He can't say.

Bob one day downloaded an app onto his iPhone, called *John's Secret Stealer*. Bob doesn't read app titles.

Since Bob is a very forgetful person, he one day forgot to leave his phone in the lockers outside of work. While standing over the super-secret shark recipe, he felt his phone in his pocket, and pulled it out. It had buzzed because he just got a text.

At that moment, *John's Secret Stealer* took a picture using Bob's phone's rear camera, sent it off to John's servers, and Bob never knew.

The next day, the entire world knew about the secret project to control sharks.

---

That's an extreme example, but it's the principal of the rule. Apple's policy is that the user is always in control - to avoid situations like Bob's.

Comment: plot twist! Bob already knew John and was watching him from a distance.