# Is it possible to create Transparent application in iOS

Tags: iphone, ipad

Is it possible to create Transparent application in iOS. means when I launch the application I should able to see home screen behind it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you ever do this?

Comment: @rptwsthi For example, because it's getting on the user's nerves? Aaaarggghhh...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this is not possible ... But you could create your own home screen background by taking a screenshot of the home screen as soon as the app starts and displaying it in the background of your running app.

You could consult the following links to take the screenshot :-

[How can I take a screenshot of the iPhone home screen programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459682/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-the-iphone-home-screen-programmatically)

**A word of warning though :- If your planning to put your app on the app store , it WILL NOT BE APPROVED. Apple does not allow this .**