# Use User Wallpaper as Background in App iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, ios7, wallpaper

So, I was using the Harmony Link app for iPhone with iOS 7, and a very cool visual effect occurred, my background showed up as the background to the window and it even had parallax motion. I noticed a similar occurrence in the Newsstand app.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to import the user's background into an iOS app? (Possibly even with parallax motion?)

Thanks.

I have seen other posts which do not address this question directly.

[image: Logitech Harmony Link]
[image: Newsstand]

Comment: You don't "import the background", your apps `UIWindow` is just transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your application's window transparent as described in this post: [iOS 7 transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924135/ios-7-display-user-wallpaper-as-uiwindow-background) but be careful as this is a non-public API.