# iOS Blur View in first view Controller

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

How is it possible to create a blur view on the first view controller in an iOS app? Like Xcode's blur view in the navigator blurring the desktop's background, I've recently recognized that Apple's 'Remote' App does the same on iOS (the background of the app is the blurred background image). Is this possible to achieve in any way using public API? Replacing the UIView by a UIBlurView only gives a gray background...

Comment: yourViewController.view.tranclucent = yes

Comment: There is no such property ..

Comment: The UIBlurView needs to be on top of the UIView, not replacing it...

Comment: Does not work either ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924135/ios-7-display-user-wallpaper-as-uiwindow-background

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041669/creating-a-blurring-overlay-view

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding blur effect to background in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953201/adding-blur-effect-to-background-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody who’s commented or answered here seems to realise that you want to blur the user’s own wallpaper and use that as the background for your root view controller, like what is achieved in Apple’s own apps (such as Remote).

While it may have been possible in earlier versions of iOS, it is currently [not possible to achieve this effect in your own app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019031/how-can-an-ios-7-app-make-itself-transparent-to-see-a-users-home-screen-image) using public APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Add this below your view: (PS: I only know the obj-C version)

```
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIToolbar* bgToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:myView.frame];
bgToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
[myView.superview insertSubview:bgToolbar belowSubview:myView];
```

Answer (score 0):

**UIVisualEffectView** in iOS will give u blur effect when u will run your project in either simulator or device Otherwise in storyboard it will display as a simple UIView with a gray background...

U need to run it and then it will give a true blur effect.

have a **look at the image below** for better understanding.

[image: have a look at an image for better understanding]

Comment: I don't know if you understood what I meant .. I know how to use the blur view in generel, but I want to blur the background image of the phone .. not anything inside of my app

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add one of the `UIBlurEffectView`s over the top of your `UIImageView` - the image view would be visible, blurred, through the blur view like below:

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurView.frame = yourFrame
imageView.addSubview(blurView)
```

Also you could remove the `blurView` using `blurView.removeFromSuperview()` or you can make it hidden `blurView.hidden = true`.