# iOS10 - transparent app background

Tags: ios, swift, background, transparent, ios10

How can I make the background of my app semi-transparent so that I can show the home screen wallpaper, like "Reminders" iOS app?

Comment: In iOS 13, this is finally possible! See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56592568/7840155

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those goodies that Apple reserves for themselves, unfortunately.

Because your app is sandboxed (can't see inside other apps), you're only allowed to use what iOS will allow you to use. When your app is loaded, the app is then what's shown on the iOS stack, independent of the home screen, and Apple doesn't make the home screen available to you.

You'll notice when you load the app that the animation shows the app maximizing over the home screen. Unfortunately, that's a bit of a visual trick, as the home screen isn't necessarily left laying there in memory.

Answer (score 1):

What if your app takes a screenshot of the home screen while launching (not sure if that is possible) and then you make that image the background image of the views in your app?

There seems to have been a private method that worked in iOS 7:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] _setApplicationIsOpaque: NO]
```

But your app would probably be rejected. And even that method has silently failed since iOS 8.