# How to make translucent window in IOS app

Tags: ios, background

I am trying to make app window translucent so that user can see a glimpse of default Home Screen wallpaper like shown in  attached screenshot of Video app

[image]

Comment: Get the screenshot of background and apply to image view and make it blur

Comment: make your view controller black with opacity 50% and make your view window.background color  = clear color

Comment: Add blur and `vibrancy effect view` in your view controller.

Comment: @NexMishra please explain me more how i will set opacity to View. Although i am using black color as view background color.Even i have tried clearColor but no success.

Comment: @NaGibToroNgo i tried your solution also but not working

Comment: @FattiKhan if i will take screenshot while app launching then that screenshot will contain home icons also right?

Comment: Probably, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953201/adding-blur-effect-to-background-in-swift) is what are you looking for...

Comment: In iOS 13, this is finally possible! See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56592568/7840155