# How to make transparent background in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, user-interface

I would like to create an app in which the Home screen wallpaper is visible.

---

See  thescreenshot below for more information:

[image: user interface example of what I want to achieve]

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: In iOS 13, this is finally possible! See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56592568/7840155

Answer (score 3):

**2019 update: In iOS 13, this is finally possible. See my answer here:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56592568/7840155

---

Although the feature was introduced in iOS 7, it is still a private method only used in Apple’s apps. There is no public API available.

Please file a feature enhancement radar if you would like to see it introuduced for third-parties.

Comment: Thanks , Can you share the third party URL ?

Comment: @gauravgupta Go to [Apple Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com/) and file a bug, which will be duped, as many of us have requested enhancement to this API. Please accept and vote up my answer if you think it was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know it it is possible, but you can create screenshot of iOS active screen and use it in your program as an background image and put other views on top of it.

Comment: Thanks, But it is an alternate, Is there any other option ?

Comment: @gauravgupta Without official API support, no