# Get user's background image

Tags: ios7, blur

In the Phone app in iOS 7 you can still see the user's background. Is it possible for third-party devs to create this effect i.e. get the user's background?

[image: iOS 7 Phone app]

Comment: You mean the background of the home screen?

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459682/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-the-iphone-home-screen-programmatically

Comment: @KevinJantzer Yes, the background of the homescreen. And no, that won't help since it is a private API. Since Apple is using it in its own app I figured there would be an API to do so.

Comment: So it was helpful; you learned that it's not possible expect with a private API which means NO, you can't capture the home screen background. Just because Apple does it, doesn't mean there's a public API for it. Apple has many private API's for their apps that aren't available to other developers

Comment: No, it was not helpful. I know it is not possible on < iOS 7 (reconfirmed by your link) but since Apple is using it in its own apps as of iOS 7 I figured there might be an API.

Comment: @yoeriboven : Did u get the answer ? If not, I have done a similar stuff of getting user's background. I mean the background of the App.