# Show a view on main screen while the app is in background in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Thanks in advance.
Is it possible to show a capture screen like assistive  touch view in ios when we click on application icon.Means i want to show the iPad screen and top on the with transparent background a view need to display.

I want to create an app like this after clicking the app icon  i want a screen like this on my main screen and i can able to customize it and capture the selected area. is it possible to do that. and is there any api for that.[image]

Comment: yes it is possible. it is called splash screen, you can it transparent

Comment: Will you provide some example for that so that i can proceed ...

Comment: http://www.iphonehacks.com/2014/01/customize-ios-7-springtomize-3.html  check it i think it'll help u

Answer (score 5):

i don't think you are allowed to capture the home screen in public api. this question had similar request.

[How can I take a screenshot of the iPhone home screen programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459682/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-the-iphone-home-screen-programmatically)

`UIGetScreenImage()` mentioned in the answer is very useful, if you only targeting Jailbroken phones.

However, i found an open source library called "Record My screen", which claim can

> Record the display even on non-jailbroken iPhones.

I personally didn't test that, since i believe Apple would somehow find that and pull the app off (that happened to several apps before). If you really interested in it, maybe you can learn something from that library.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: am asking if when i click on a app icon is it possible to show a view with min size and transparent background in home screen.