# iPhone home screen capture programmatically from app

Tags: ios7

I have a jailbroken iPhone device. I want to programmatically take iOS 7/iPhone screenshots (2/3/4 screens) of the app icons and store them in an image view. However, I don't want to capture the app's home screen, that is the iPhone's main screen.

Is there a solution?

Comment: See this answer. There seems to be a way using private API code. [http://stackoverflow.com/a/13460128/2666120](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13460128/2666120)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I take a screenshot of the iPhone home screen programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459682/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-the-iphone-home-screen-programmatically)